# Skip rows from csv file

Tags: .net-core, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/IReaderConfiguration.cs) to read a csv file and I want to skip a certain number of rows from the beginning of the file. Is it possible to use "ShouldSkipRecord" in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ShouldSkipRecord` if you know that the rows all start with say a certain character.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("# Something here.");
            writer.WriteLine("# Another line we don't need.");
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Name");
            writer.WriteLine("1,George");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = row => row[0].StartsWith("#");                

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If you know you want to skip say the first 2 rows, this would work.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Something here.");
            writer.WriteLine("Another line we don't need.");
            writer.WriteLine("Id,Name");
            writer.WriteLine("1,George");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                csv.Read();
            }

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is what worked for me:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        ShouldSkipRecord = (row) =>
                        {
                            //your logic for skipping records goes here

                           return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Record[7]);
                        }
                    };
using (var reader = new StreamReader("CsvFilePath"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
             lst = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working and tested:

```
            // * Below config will remove those top rows start with comments 
            //   (start with '#') and avoid parsing error on .ToList().
            var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) { 
                    ShouldSkipRecord = (row) => row.Row[0].StartsWith("#")
            };
            IEnumerable<Foo> records = new List<Foo>();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("CsvFilePath"))
            {                    
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
                {
                    records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
                }
            }
            if(records != null && records.Count() > 0)
            { 
                // ...
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**